# how to pass parameter on completion block in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, function, parameters

I am trying to declare a function with couple of blocks inside it, when I will call the function from viewdidload method, these parameters should perform accordongly

```
-(void) alertViewOn:(UILabel*)LabelTextX :(UIButton*)ButtonA :(UIButton*)ButtonB :(UIImage*)ImageX {


UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Pet Name" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

//Show TextField
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Pet Name", @"Name");
 }];

//Set Ok Button
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UITextField *textField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
    self.labelText2.text   = textField.text;

}];
[alert addAction:ok];

//Set ADD Button
UIAlertAction* addPet = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add More" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    self.button4.hidden = NO;
    self.button5.hidden = NO;
    self.image2.hidden = NO;

}];
[alert addAction:addPet];

//Set Cancel Button
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}];
[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here I want to pass the parameter LabelTextX to labelText2 ; ButtonA to button4 ; ButtonY to button5 and ImageX to image2 . I am totally new in objective-c and finding it difficult even to declare a function !!! Please any kind person help ....

Comment: create  the __block variable to assign the variable and access in the block methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(void) alertViewOn:(UILabel*)LabelTextX :(UIButton*)ButtonA :   (UIButton*)ButtonB :(UIImageView*)ImageX {

UIAlertController* alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter Pet Name" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

//Show TextField
[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField)
 {
     textField.placeholder = NSLocalizedString(@"Pet Name", @"Name");
 }];

//Set Ok Button
UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    UITextField *textField = alert.textFields.firstObject;
    LabelTextX.text   = textField.text;

}];

[alert addAction:ok];

//Set ADD Button
UIAlertAction* addPet = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Add More" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    ButtonA.hidden = NO;
    ButtonB.hidden = NO;
    ImageX.hidden = NO;

}];

[alert addAction:addPet];

//Set Cancel Button
UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleDestructive handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){

    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}];

[alert addAction:cancel];
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

And then called the function like this ...

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed15:(id)sender {
         [self alertViewOn:_labelText15 :_button30 :_button31 :_image15];
}
```